# Question about the relevance of margins or display properties for absolutely positioned or fixed positioned elements

Tags: css

If absolutely positioned or fixed positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow, is it still advisable to use margins to position those elements

or

would it be just the same if the **[ top, right, bottom, left] position properties** are used instead to move the elements around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's *not* advisable.

The properties - `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` - exist to position such styled elements accordingly. Using `margin`, although may work, would not be the *correct* positioning property and could lead to undefined behavior.

With that said, there are obviously more than one way to do things in CSS. So in the end, it's up to you.